# Send animated text using mail

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

hello every one i am using this code to give glowing effect to my UILable text.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(glowMarquee)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];


-(void)glowMarquee {
    alph = (alph == 1) ? 0.1 : 1;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"alpha" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];        
    lblpreview.alpha = alph;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

now is this possible to send this text in mail with the glowing effect?
thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot send executable code in an email and trust that it runs on the other end.

Comment: Well, not entirely true. You could probably use some scripting in the email to recreate the text, but that doesn't mean it's gonna be easy.

Comment: Yeah you can use html content in the mail. So try that if that works.